# Read content of a text file with umlauts in Erlang

Tags: file, utf-8, erlang, diacritics

I'm trying to read the content of a text file which can contain umlauts and stuff like this. I already red the stuff about unicode in Erlang but I still can't figure out how to read the file properly.
Here is my code for reading the file:

`reader (File) ->
case io:get_line(File,'') of
    eof -> [];
    {error, Reason} -> Reason;
    Line -> [Line] ++ reader(File)
end.`

But in the end my result is: `Ã¼` when reading an `ü`

How must I convert `Line` to get the expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file looks like it's encoded in utf-8, but Erlang read it in latin1.

Specify encoding when getting the handle:

```
file:open(Fname, [read, {encoding,utf8}])
```

The syntax might be off, I copy pasted it from [the manual](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html).